# Polynomial and Function

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, polynomials

I have been give a question if 
  $ f(x) = x^3-1 $
then show 
$$  \frac {f(b) - f(a)} {b-a} =b^2+ab+a^2 $$

how to show that the above fraction is equal to that polynomial if $ f(X) = x^3-1 $ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$  \frac {f(b) - f(a)} {b-a}$$

$$ = \frac {b^3 - 1 - a^3 + 1} {b-a}$$

$$ = \frac {b^3 - a^3} {b-a}$$

$$ = \frac {(b-a)(b^2+ab+a^2)} {b-a} $$

$$ = b^2 + ab + a^2 $$

**Formula used.**

$$x^3 - y^3 = (x - y)(x^2 + xy + y^2)$$

Answer (score 3):

It results from the high-school identity:
$$x^3-y^3=(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2).$$
More generally:
$$x^n-y^n=(x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+x^{n-3}y^2+\dots+xy^{n-2}+y^{n-1}).$$

Comment: Thanks. I forgot everything. :D and where is $ -1 $ 
?

Comment: It is disappears from the numerator since it is a constant.

Comment: @Bernard Does this apply if the variables are $u$ and $t$?

Comment: These formulae are valid in any  commutative ring (not proved  in high-school, though…)